# Embedding of continuous functions into differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, ring-theory

This question refers to a solution printed in the current (December 2013, **120**(10)) issue of *The American Mathematical Monthly*, *p.* 944.  There, the authors intend to show that any ring homomorphism from the set $C$ of continuous functions **R** $\to$ **R** to the set of differentiable functions **R** $\to$ **R** cannot be an injection.  (Note we are talking of only an algebraïc homomorphism.  That is, we have no topology on the function spaces.)

I follow the solution through "the image of [such a homomorphism] $\phi$ consists only of constant functions."  What I don't get is the following (and terminal) sentence, "In particular, $\phi$ is not injective."  This does not follow from cardinality considerations, as $C$ has the same cardinality as **R**.  Could someone please elucidate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incidentally, I solved that problem (though the "Also solved by" list didn't appear, damn it!!). My final argument was: If $\phi$ were injective, then $C$ would be isomorphic to a subring of $\mathbb R$, which will be an integral domain; but clearly $C$ is not an integral domain.

Comment: Ah, that clears it up.  Thank you.  Yeah, I noticed the absence of the list of other solvers as well.  An editorial error is my guess.  It will probably appear in corrections later.